# Random variable X with values on [0,2]

Tags: statistics

The CDF is $c(3{x^5} - 15{x^4} + 20{x^3})$ and I'm supposed to say which constant c makes it a well defined CDF. Wouldn't any integer make it a well defined CDF? I don't understand.

I'm also supposed to be able to find the PDF from this but I'm not sure how. What is the relation between PDF and CDF? Should I integrate or something? If you give me a hint on what I need to do then I will do it. Thank you.

Comment: Substituting $x=2$ should give you the total probability which should be normalized. Knowing the CDF, then you can differentiate it to find the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $F_X(2)=P(X\le 2)=1$ so $16c=1\iff c=\frac1{16}$. Moreover we have

$$F_X(x)=P(X\le x)=\int_0^x f_X(t)dt,\; x\in[0,2]$$
hence $f_X(x)=F_X'(x)=\frac1{16}(15x^4-60x^3+60x^2)$.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I also need to find ${\mathop{\rm P}\nolimits} (X > {1 \over 2}|X \le 1)$. I'm not sure what the | means, does it mean and? So that would mean I need to find ${\mathop{\rm P}\nolimits} ({1 \over 2} < X \le 1)$?

Comment: @Ahmed it does not mean "and", but "under condition that". What is the probability that $X>\frac12$ if we allready know that $X\leq1$. You can use the (defining) equality $P(X>\frac12\mid X\leq1)P(X\leq1)=P(X>\frac12\text{ and }X\leq1)$. The factors $P(X\leq1)$ and $P(X>\frac12\text{ and }X\leq1)$ can be found using the CDF.